# Adding prefix to string in a file

Tags: python, string, append

Well i have a sort of telephone directory in a .txt file,
what i want to do is find all the numbers with this pattern e.g. 829-2234 and append the number 5 to the beginning of the numbers.

so the result now becomes 5829-2234.

my code begins like this:

```
import os
import re
count=0

#setup our regex
regex=re.compile("\d{3}-\d{4}\s"}

#open file for scanning
f= open("samplex.txt")

#begin find numbers matching pattern
for line in f:
    pattern=regex.findall(line)
    #isolate results
    for word in pattern:
        print word
        count=count+1 #calculate number of occurences of 7-digit numbers
# replace 7-digit numbers with 8-digit numbers
        word= '%dword' %5
```

well i don't really know how to append the prefix 5 and then overwrite the 7-digit number with 7-digit number with 5 prefix. I tried a few things but all failed :/

Any tip/help would be greatly appreciated :)

Thanks

Comment: 'Append prefix' is a contradiction in terms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're almost there, but you got your string formatting the wrong way. As you know that `5` will always be in the string (because you're adding it), you do:

```
word = '5%s' % word
```

Note that you can also use string concatenation here:

```
word = '5' + word
```

Or even use `str.format()`:

```
word = '5{}'.format(word)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're doing it with regex then use `re.sub`:

```
>>> strs = "829-2234   829-1000 111-2234  "
>>> regex = re.compile(r"\b(\d{3}-\d{4})\b")
>>> regex.sub(r'5\1', strs)
'5829-2234   5829-1000 5111-2234  '
```